# Assertion error retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I get `java.lang.assetionerror` when I send `@QueryMap` without this API works just fine

Any fix for this?

edit 1

code

```
 @GET("/api/get-order-history/{id}")
    Call<SomeClass> getOrderList(@QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, String> params,@Path("id") String id )
```

Comment: how are you using it ?

Comment: Please attach the piece of code that causes the error along with the exception stack trace.

Comment: @Blackbelt added code

Comment: @Egor please check and advice

Answer (score 7):

It is evaluated sequentially. Just use `@Path` before `@QueryMap` and it should be fine.